# How to mock a rest API in python

Tags: python, networking, python-requests

I have a application running which some where in the midst uses some rest API call. Now for stress test I want to replace this API call with some mock server. Is there any way to do it.

Let me try to put it programmatically so it gets some clarity. I've a some server running at port say 8080

```
# main server
from flask import Flask
from myapp import Myapp

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/find_solution", methods=["GET"])
def solution() :
    return app.sol.find_solution(), 200

def start():
    app.sol = Myapp()
    return app
```

Now this Myapp

```
#myapp
import requests
class Myapp:
    def __init__():
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def find_solution():
        myparameters = {"Some parameter that I filled"}
        return self.session.request('GET', 'http://api.weatherstack.com/current', params=myparameters)
```

Now here I want to replace behavior of `http://api.weatherstack.com/current` without modifying code. i.e some way where I can replace call to `http:api.weatherstack.com/current` to my local system server.

Any help of lead is appreciated. I am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You can pass a parameter to the method `find_solution()` and just use the parameter in your request.

Comment: @ShaikhAbuzar I didn't get it what do you mean by using parameter in request.

Comment: Please have a look at the answer I have posted below

Answer (score 0):

So for your scenario if you want to test your api flask comes with mock test client feature.

```
test_client = app.test_client()
test_client.post('/find_solution', headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}, data=data)
```

So for this scenario you can create test cases and get test client instance inside your test case and perform tests at api level. This is a light weight test method rather than the one proposed by you

Refer to the following link for official flask documentation

```
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/#keeping-the-context-around
```

Cheers